# How to play a material's shader in an image through c# ? (Unity 5.2.0f3)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I would like to obtain the same effect as in Seasons After Fall in Unity 5.2.0f3 for a 2D project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCIhs.gif

Here the trailer, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmAWybFKNh8

I'm trying to play a material composed of a shader in a Sprite Renderer that way:

```
spriteRenderer = background.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
spriteRendererMaterial = Instantiate(spriteRenderer.sharedMaterial);
spriteRendererMaterial.SetFloat("Slider_Dissolve", 1.5f);
spriteRenderer.material = spriteRendererMaterial;
```

But then I would like to apply that same material in an image but it doesn't work when I launch the game even if I can see the material being updated in the "Project View".

The problem was also discussed in their forum but note that there are absolutely no masks in any of my components compared to: https://forum.unity.com/threads/trying-to-animate-an-image-component-material-shader.265023/ The effect was also discussed here: Season Change Reveal Effect

I'm running low on solutions any help would be appreciated.

Here a topic we though it would help: https://forum.unity.com/threads/material-isnt-updating-when-using-setfloat.530548/ Unfortunately nope...

Below is a coroutine i want to execute after button click :

```
IEnumerator WaitForInteractiveElementTransform(Animator animator)
{
    if (animator != null)
    {
        while (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length >
        animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
if (animatorBackground != null)
{
    animatorBackground.SetBool("On", true);
}
else
{
    P4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    P4Fantasy.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
state = SceneState.Unreal;
StartCoroutine(SetMaterialFloatOverTime(spriteRendererMaterial, 1.5f, "Slider_Dissolve"));

private IEnumerator SetMaterialFloatOverTime(Material material, float 
duration, string propertyName)
{
    float timer = 0;
    while (timer < duration)
    {
        material.SetFloat(propertyName, timer);
        spriteRenderer.material = material;
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
 }
```

The coroutine SetMaterialFloatOverTime updates weel Slider_Dissolve property but the image on scene is not refreshed every time this property value changes.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

It does look like a Unity bug to me. If you are talking about Image as a UI image element there is another way you could provide individual values them without creating Individual material instances. If I need a fade out effect on UI, in shader I use vertex color. When you change color of a UI element Unity sends that color as a vertex color. So while they use the same material, the RGBA values can basically be used as 4 sliders for various effects.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your reply. Yes, I am talking about UI Image element. So, do you think only an upgrade of Unity version will fix this ? I will try that and let you know.

Comment: @gjamot If it is a bug then it should. BTW, take a look at Shader.SetGlobal... function. When you have some global effects similar to the one you are talking about you would often want to manipulate many shaders and many materials with the same slider, SetGlobal will help with that, it did for me.